# In MS Outlook VBA, how does the structure of a Table object make a row count unreliable?

Tags: vba, outlook

The [Table object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.table) does not have a property `count`. Instead, it has the method [`GetRowCount`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.table.getrowcount). But that comes with the warning that it's not reliable and may return an approximate count and yield an error.

Does anyone here know what's different about the structure of a Table object that prevents VBA from knowing its count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GetRowCount` method corresponds to the [IMAPITable::GetRowCount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/imapitable-getrowcount) method which explains possible reasons like memory constraints and etc. You may find the following description helpful:

> Use `GetRowCount` to find out how many rows a table holds before making a call to the `IMAPITable::QueryRows` method to retrieve the data. If there are less than twenty rows in the table, it is safe to call `QueryPosition` to retrieve the whole table. If there are more than twenty rows in the table, consider making multiple calls to `QueryPosition` and limit the number of rows retrieved in each call.

> Some tables do not support GetRowCount and return `MAPI_E_NO_SUPPORT`. If `GetRowCount` is not supported, an alternative might be to call `IMAPITable::QueryPosition`. With the results from `QueryPosition`, you can determine the relationship between the current row and last row.

> When `GetRowCount` returns MAPI_E_BUSY because it is temporarily unable to retrieve a row count, call the `IMAPITable::WaitForCompletion` method. When `WaitForCompletion` returns, retry the call to `GetRowCount`. Another way to detect whether an asynchronous operation is in progress is to call the `IMAPITable::GetStatus` method and check the contents of the `lpulTableState` parameter.

In `Extended MAPI` (*a low-level API* on which Outlook is based on) you can specify how many rows you would like to get using the [IMAPITable::QueryRows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/imapitable-queryrows) method.

Answer (score 1):

Some tables (such as large GAL or LDAP address book provider tables) do not know how many rows they have, the best you can do is either search for a particular entry or enumerate the rows one at a time (which is a bad idea).

This usually does not apply to the folder contents tables  - you can always get the count. But the row count can always change while you are looping through the collection, so it is always better to use `Items.Find/FindNext/Restrict` or use am enumerator when looping through the items (if you absolutely have to).